# How to research graphics cards

Tags: hardware, graphics

How would you go about choosing which graphics card to purchase. In the past I've run into situations with graphics cards whose drivers weren't that solid in Linux.

Answer (score 6):

You can find out if the card you're [looking for is certified here](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/category/VIDEO).

- [Component Catalog](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to know whether a video card is supported, you have two main guides.

For free drivers, check the [X.org site's list](http://xorg.freedesktop.org/wiki/Projects/Drivers?action=show&redirect=VideoDrivers) of supported cards.

For proprietary drivers, check the manufacturers' sites. Most people will be concerned with the proprietary drivers for [Nvidia](http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html) and [ATI](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx), the two leading video card manufacturers.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I'd add.... search for a specific card here in askubuntu to look if there are known problems.

Comment: @johannix remember to accept the answer you found most helpful.